# Jquery error "Uncaught ReferenceError: SPR is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am trying to use jquery countdown from http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html. But I am getting strange kind of error. It says "`Uncaught ReferenceError: SPR is not defined`".

[Here](http://dressika.com/products/11/) is the link of my site and I am using Django as framework to work with jquery plugin.

Following is my code.

```
$year = {{ object.expire_date|date:"Y" }};
$month = {{ object.expire_date|date:"m" }};
$day = {{ object.expire_date|date:"d" }};

$exp_date = new Date( $year, $month -1, $day);

$("#defaultCountdown").countdown({
    until: $exp_date,
    onExpiry: fadeExpireOut

});
function fadeExpireOut(){
    $("#defaultCountdown").fadeOut();
}
```

I am using following tag to display the countdown.

```
<span id="defaultCountdown"></span>
```

Please see error details by inspecting element. The same code is working fine in development but not at production server.

Comment: In development like on local server it also works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this javascript statement:

```
 SPR.$("textarea[data-product-id=3712888641]").keyup(sprUpdateCount).trigger("keyup");
```

that gets executed immediately and, at the time it is executed, the variable SPR doesn't exist.

Looking at your link, the offending code is at line 2631, inside the following script block:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
          function sprUpdateCount(e){
            var $el = SPR.$(e.currentTarget);
            SPR.$(".spr-form-review-body-charactersremaining").html('(' + (1500 - $el.val().length) + ')');
          }
          SPR.$("textarea[data-product-id=3712888641]").keyup(sprUpdateCount).trigger("keyup");
</script>
```

Comment: So what I need to do to fix it. You just gave me a clue about the exact issue. How to make it work?

Comment: Well it depends... can you tell me what the SPR variable does?

Comment: If you are working on code not written by you, start by just commenting out this line and then you can figure it out later (hopefully you will get to know the code better over time).

Comment: SPR value comes from keithwood.name jquery dependencies. You can see it in inspect elements. This is not the function I've added for my project. Thing is that this works fine for other projects but not working for this one. Even I've tested it in development and no such error. For details see /* http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html. The file is "jquery.countdown.js.

Comment: Are you  sure? I visited http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js but I couldn't find any global variable called "SPR". 

From what I can tell SPR would be used to store some complex object so that you can then reference DOM elements based on it, I'm just guessing since I can't even find where the variable is declared.

If you are using code that you copied and pasted from somewhere else (which I believe is the case here) just do this: every time you see `SPR.$`, just delete `SPR.` (delete the dot too!) and just leave the dollar sign e.g `$("textarea` etc.... this way it should work

Comment: I got your point...but what about the file jquery.countdown.js line 184. It not at all related to SRP. Just last piece of expert advise and I will be able to get it done.

Comment: Yes I saw line 184, what do you want to know about it?

Comment: By the way, does my answer respond to your question? Can you mark it as accepted? In your last comment you are now asking me stuff that is unrelated to the question...

Comment: Tried everything and lastly I've removed jquery from the template completely to rebuild it myself from scratch. So I am not sure if your answer corresponds to the problem. So I am not sure what to do. Kindly bare with me for sometime coz it will take some time for me to rebuild. After that I will respond to your suggestion with honesty. By accepting your answer as yes hopefully. But if I accepted your answer without confirming it then people looking at this question will be distracted. Thanks again

Comment: Don't remove JQuery. Leave only JQuery and the count down code, and leave them in this order (Jquery first). Then delete every other `script` tag.

Comment: You have other JS that is failing and as a result the execution is blocked and the countdown doesn't execute. If you delete everything except jquery and the countdown, then the countdown will work. This is a question and answer site man, I can't make the website for you...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with your first name so I wrongly assumed you were a man. I shouldn't have, preconceptions are always bad. Regarding the code, did you try removing all JS except JQuery and the countdown code?

Comment: I did and fixed it. You were right it was not letting the script execute. Also original template had the old version of min.js. Thanks for help anyway. I will upload it you can see it. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad it worked! PS are you building your own startup? If so, good luck :-)

Comment: Yes I am building my own startups and this is the first one scheduled to be launched by end of July. Hope you like the outlook. :-)